# Laravel broadcast pusher is not working in server

Tags: php, laravel, broadcast, pusher

Everything works fine on my local server
But in the server it is not working

There are no errors in the server

i'm checked

broadcasting.php file

```
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
            ],
        ]
```

.env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_APP_ID=my-pusher-app-id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=my-pusher-key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=my-pusher-secret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

```
use App\Events\MyEvent;

        MyEvent::dispatch($id);
        broadcast(new MyEvent($id));
        event(new MyEvent($id));
```

installed
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server

```
php artisan config:clear
```

config/app.php file

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class
```

Why does it works local server but not in the real server?

Comment: Check the browser dev-tools under network, and see if the WebSocket connection is initiated successfully

Comment: solved
env file
Change QUEUE_CONNECTION=databases to QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync